# Laravel: how to mock a class

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, mocking

Are there any good tutorial that explain how to mock a class in Laravel?

I am a bit confused, since the Laravel documentation (5.2) only talks about mocking facades, jobs and events (the last two I have never used to be honest, and jobs I dont know what it is).

This is basicly the scenario (simplified as example) I want to test:

```
?php 
class A
{
  protected $B;
  public function __construct($classB)
    {
        $this->B = $classB;
    }
}
class B implements myInterface
{
   public function methodToTest();
}
```

I want to mock class B that I send to Class A constructor. Should I make new files for interface and the mocking class? Or perhaps make use of mockery library (which I see some do on stackOverflow)? Where can I read about the mockery class by the way; I cant find it in the Laravel documentation.

I apologize in advance for being a bit confused.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Laravel's testing documentation is limited because it extends PHPUnit, for which there is already ample documentation:

https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html

In the most basic case, you'll do something like this:

```
$stub = $this->createMock(B::class);
$a = new A($stub);
```

You can read the documentation linked above for all the fancy features provided by PHPUnit.